# Precise integer matrix rank with Eigen (or another C++ linear algebra library)

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have a rectangular integer matrix and I'm trying to compute its rank with Eigen.

If I understand correctly, the way to compute matrix rank with Eigen is via a rank-revealing decomposition.
According to Eigen tutorial, section [“Linear algebra and decompositions”](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html), subsection “Rank-revealing decompositions”:

> any rank computation depends on the choice of an arbitrary threshold, since practically no floating-point matrix is exactly rank-deficient

But it says nothing about integer matrices.

Is there a way to find the *exact* rank of an integer matrix?

If Eigen can't do this I would be happy to hear suggestions regarding other C++ linear algebra systems that can.

Comment: What size of ints? For standard ints that are typically 32 bits, calculating rank with doubles should provide exact results. For larger sizes you might need to write your own decomp.

Comment: You could use one of Eigen's LU solvers with a custom rational type (probably, this won't be the most efficient way possible)

Comment: @doug You will get non-exact results as soon as you have a division which can't be represented exactly as `double` (like `1.0/3.0`)

Comment: @chtz - Sure, that's why I limited it to 32 bit ints with double calcs. Setting the threshold high (for a double) will cover the much smaller errors. But a custom rational would be a nice approach.